# Why am I getting this error , it's unusual

Tags: java

```
public class Check {
    public void do() {
        System.out.println("Check");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Check obj=new Check();
        obj.do();
    }
}
```

The errors am getting are 
' ; ' expected 
Illegal start of type

```
public void do()
```

identifier expected

```
public void do()
```

Answer (score 7):

`do` is a *keyword* (it's used in a `do` `while` loop).

It cannot be used as a function name. This is confusing the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is the list of keywords in java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html

You can not use it for method, variable... :)